# how to set custom discrete color scale in 3D scatterplot with R and plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have this R dataframe

```
Varieta <- c("Habanero rosso", "Habanero rosso", "Habanero rosso", "Naga Morich", "Naga Morich",    "Naga Morich", "Fatalii Yellow",  "Moruga Yellow", "Erotico Arancio")
a_color <- c(8.350, 40.532, 38.904, 44.942, 43.132, 42.994, 38.021, 37, 36)
b_color <- c(8, 40, 38, 44, 43, 42, 38, 37, 36)
L_color <- c(4.350, 1.532, 3.904, 4.942, 3.132, 2.994, 3.021, 3.56, 36.54)

df <- data.frame (Varieta, a_color, b_color, L_color)
```

I wrote this piece of code in R

```
# colors definition
pal =               c('rgb(255, 0, 0)', 
                      'rgb(75, 0, 0)', 
                      'rgb(150, 200, 0)', 
                      'rgb(255, 255, 0)', 
                      'rgb(220, 100, 0)')

pal = setNames(pal, c("Habanero rosso",  
                      "Naga Morich",     
                      "Fatalii Yellow",  
                      "Moruga Yellow",   
                      "Erotico Arancio"))



fig <- plot_ly(type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'markers') 

fig <- fig %>% add_trace(data = DF,
                                x = ~a_color,
                                y = ~b_color,
                                z = ~L_color,
                
                        color = ~Varieta,
                        colorscale = pal, 
                  
                        marker = list(size = 5,
                                      line = list(color = 'rgb(100, 100, 100)',
                                                  width = 2)))

fig <- fig %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "a",
                                           gridcolor = "rgb(0, 0, 0)"),
                              yaxis = list(title = "b",
                                           gridcolor = "rgb(0, 0, 0)"),
                              zaxis = list(title = "L",
                                           gridcolor = "rgb(0, 0, 0)")))
```

At the end I receive this error

*1: 'scatter3d' objects don't have these attributes: 'colorscale'*

How can I use my own color scale in 3D scatterplot in R and plotly?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: I modified the Question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own custom colors in a 3D plotly scatterplot DON'T specify "type = 'scatter3d'", just don't specify the type of chart, it will be inferred automatically, then use the option "colors" and the html color notations

```
fig <- plot_ly(data = DF,
                x = ~a_color,
                y = ~b_color,
                z = ~L_color,
                
                color = ~Varieta,
                colors = c('#ff8c00',   #Erotico arancio = arancio
                           '#bdb76b',   #Fatalii Yellow  = senape
                           '#ff0000',   #Habanero Rosso  = rosso  
                           '#ffff00',   #Moruga Yellow   = giallo
                           '#800000'),  #Naga Morich     = rosso scuro  
                  
                marker = list(size = 5,
                              line = list(color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                                          width = 1)))
```